# Headphone Jack works, but only produces low sound

Tags: audio, headphones

The sound works, but only produces a low sound. Additionally, I have check the system preference's sound section, and checked the output, mute check, and made sure the headphones were chosen as the output. However still emits low sound. Is the jack damaged in some way and how can I fix it?

Comment: It would be good to provide some details such as what version of macOS you're running? What have you actually got plugged into the headphone jack (headphones, other device, etc) and if possible the brand/model. Also, have you tested it with something else plugged into the headphone socket?

Comment: By 'low sound', do you mean low _volume level_, or sound that has too much bass (low frequencies) and not enough treble (high frequencies?) Please edit your question to reflect this clarification. Also - what are you using to listen? Headphones/earbuds or a connection to external speakers?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you've had no issues when using your computer's speakers to produce output so you could download an EQ like [Boom 2](http://www.globaldelight.com/boom/index.php) or eqMac to bump up the volume via software. Just be careful using your speakers afterwards if you have to turn it up really high.

Another solution which I think is a bit safer but can be a bit of a hassle depending on your personal preference would be to buy an [external sound card](https://www.amazon.ca/Sabrent-External-Adapter-Windows-AU-MMSA/dp/B00IRVQ0F8/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1481345457&sr=8-2&keywords=external%20sound%20card). Depending on what you get you may gain functionality and if it doesn't work you can return the item and you can be pretty sure it's a software issue.

I also would like to make sure that you're not using high impedence headphones that need an amp because if you are then that would explain your issue but I'm assuming you're not.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the cord is plugged all the way in and that there isn't anything in the audio jack. I've had this issue happen several times before where some lint or dust buildup wasn't letting the headphones plug all the way in.